# Unmarshaling xml with html entities using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to load wikipedia revision histories into POJOs, so I'm using JAXB to unmarshall the wikipeida data dump (well, individual pages of it).  The problem is that the text nodes occasionally contain entities that are not defined in the wikipedia xml dump.  eg: ° (`&deg;' pleases keep in mind that I do not know the complete set of entities that I need to be able to read.  My input file is 3tb, so let's just assume that everything html can render is in there.).

How can I configure JAXB to handle entities that are not valid xml?

Here is the SAX Exception that JAXB throws when it encounters an undefined entity:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

 - with linked exception:

[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity "deg" was referenced, but not declared.]

    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:315)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:481)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:199)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:168)

    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)

    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:184)

    at com.stottlerhenke.tools.wikiparse.WikipediaIO.readPage(WikipediaIO.java:73)

    at com.stottlerhenke.tools.wikiparse.WikipediaIO.main(WikipediaIO.java:53)

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity "deg" was referenced, but not declared.

    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:195)
```

*Edit:* The input that triggered that exception is the complete revision history for the wikipedia article on the [Arctic Circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artic_Circle).  The XSD used to generate the JAXB classes is here: http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.3.xsd

**Edit:** The source of this problem was an error on my part -- I was using an initial extractor that did not maintain encoded entities properly.  However, I did find a way around this, should anyone have the problem I *thought* I had.  See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hack, but it works in a pinch.

I downloaded the html entity definitions from w3.org, and set the doctype of the input xml file to xhtml-transitional, but directed the doctype url to a local dtd:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

xhtml1-transitional.dtd, in turn, requires:

- xhtml-lat1.ent
- xhtml-special.ent
- xhtml-symbol.ent

which I sucked down and put along side xhtml1-transitional.dtd

(All files are available at: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/ )

Like I said, ugly as hell, but it *did* seem to do the job.

Comment: Is there a reason you had to make the dtd document local?  What happened with a remove DTD document?

Comment: w3.org returned an error code when JAXB tried to retrieve the DTD directly -- even though the url worked in a browser.  I surmised that w3.org is blocking access to dtds/etc based on user agents to stop people from accessing their servers from APIs.  (w3.org posted a plea for people to stop writing apps that do that a year or so ago: http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic )  I'm not sure what you mean by "what happened with a remove DTD document?".

Comment: You probably want to use an XML catalog to point at a local copy rather than changing the DOCTYPE itself.  See http://xml.apache.org/commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

Resolving entities is not the job of JAXB's. It's the job of the underlying
XML parser.

What you could do is:

- read the data yourself using DOM
- replace all unresolved entities by something you wish
- then, let JAXB handle the result

Comment: Since Jaxb abstracts away from the XML parser, I think it should provide some means to fix things that need to be managed at the parser level (maybe just by using dependency injection to supply a different parser).  Then again, I was giving JAXB invalid input -- so what did I expect? ;)